# Do/while loop not working?

Tags: javascript, do-while

Here's the code:

```
do {
    var selection=prompt("Enter password","");
} while(selection!="pass"||selection!="winner");
```

I'm trying to allow both "pass" and "winner" as a password for the prompt, but something goes wrong around the `||selection!="winner"`, because the code works without it. I feel like the answer is right under my nose but I can't find it

Comment: evaluate each possibility, and write the truth table of your exit condition

Comment: A do-while executes at least once, and then checks the condition.

Comment: `... while(!(selection=="pass"||selection=="winner"))`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks minimal understanding of basic logic. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard for a single string to equal both "pass" and "winner" at the same time.

You probably want `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Sure there is. Read up on DeMorgan's laws. `while (! (selection === 'pass' || selection === 'winner'))`